# How to set select attribute to radiobuttons in ES 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make radiobuttons using a JSON-file in Javascript. I'm not really sure how I can set the checked attribute so only one radiobutton can be selected.

```js
const makeArtistRadioButtons = (artists) => {
    artists.forEach(artist => {
      // <div>
        // <input type="radio" value="artist"> artist name <br>
        // ...
      // </div>
      const $parent = document.querySelector(`.radiobuttons`);
      const $label = document.createElement(`label`);
      $label.innerHTML = `<input class="radio" type="radio" value="${artist}"> ${artist}`
      $parent.appendChild($label);
    });

  }
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
   <section class="radiobuttons"></section>
   <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the `input` elements the same `name` attribute so that only one of them can be `checked` at a time.

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="artist" value="${artist}"> ${artist}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the name attribute on each radio button to the same value, then only 1 radio button with that name can be selected at a time

```
 <input type='radio' name='group'                
  value=1>
 <input type='radio' name='group' 
  value=2>            
 <input type='radio' name='group'                  
  value=3>
```